# Can't setup swagger - Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, openapi

I am having a problem with setting up the swagger into my node.js application. I am using `swagger-jsdoc` and `swagger-ui-express` for creating documentation. Here are the versions

> "swagger-jsdoc": "3.5.0", "swagger-ui-express": "4.1.3"

Below is the configs, which I pass to swagger-jsdoc.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: test
  version: 3.0.0
  title: U-CRM api documentation
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
servers:
  - url: 'https://localhost:5000'
    description: Local server
tags:
- name: U-CRM
  description: CRM for university
components:
  parameters:
    $ref: 'components/parameters/index.yml'
  schemas:
    $ref: 'components/schemas/index.yml'
paths:
  $ref: '#/paths/index.yml'
```

After all, I get an error

> Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined

Actually, it is surprising to me, as I read swagger docs carefully.
What could be the problem?

Comment: https://editor.swagger.io/?_ga=2.24586106.1528292052.1581979246-1594721192.1581979246  Stick your config in there

Comment: Thanks for this, but my problem is not related to it.I know I can test there, but the problem is I split my docs into different files.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI does not support `$ref` *everywhere*. `$ref` can only be used in specific places where the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md) explicitly states that the value of a field can be a "Reference Object".

For example, `$ref` is not allowed directly under `paths`, under `components/parameters` and `components/schemas` - you can only reference *individual* paths, parameters and schemas.

The correct version of your example is:

```yaml
paths:
  /foo:
    $ref: '#/paths/index.yml#/~1foo'  # $ref to root node `/foo` in `paths/index.yml`
  /bar:
    $ref: '#/paths/index.yml#/~1bar'  # $ref to root node `/bar` in `paths/index.yml`

components:
  parameters:
    param1:
      $ref: 'components/parameters/index.yml#/param1'
    param2:
      $ref: 'components/parameters/index.yml#/param2'
  schemas:
    schema1:
      $ref: 'components/schemas/index.yml#/schema1'
    schema2:
      $ref: 'components/schemas/index.yml#/schema2'
```

If you want to use `$ref` in random places, you'll have to pre-process your definition using a parser/tool that can resolve arbitrary $refs; this will give you a valid OpenAPI file that can be used with OpenAPI-compliant tools. One such pre-processing tool is [json-refs](https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs), you can find an example of pre-processing [here](https://azimi.me/2015/07/16/split-swagger-into-smaller-files.html#tools).

Comment: The whole problem is at getting an error - `Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined`. And that's not related to ref-s at least.