# springdoc-openapi : not showing correct tag when init

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-openapi to create API documentation and I'm using `$ref` to reference the external yaml file.
Here's my config:

```yaml
tags:
  - name: example
    description: 'Description for Example'
paths:
  /example/{id}/{pathParam2}:
    get:
      $ref: './demo-ten-controller/demoTenMethodFunctionCuaApi.yml'
```

```yaml
#demoTenMethodFunctionCuaApi.yml
tags:
  - example
summary: 'Swagger Example'
operationId: 'findPetsByStatus'
```

But when I open my swagger-ui, it's not correct tags as I want:

[image: Swagger-ui]

And then, when I click to show detail The API, it will be correct.

[image: Swagger-ui]

Please help me correct the tag when init.

Comment: You can't use `$ref` under `get`/`post`/etc., you can only use `$ref` under path names i.e. under `/example/{id}/{pathParam2}`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343640/113116)

Comment: @huynhtamhao, Please add your java code that helped you generate these tags.