# OpenApi file with multiple/consecutive $ref elements in paths is giving duplicate mapping key

Tags: yaml, openapi

I have following OpenAPI file, my intention is to define employee, customer, projects endpoints in its own yaml files.  However, using the below code is resulting in 'duplicating mapping key' error - this is because the use of '$ref'(consecutively).  Is there a way to achieve this segregation?

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: example  
servers:
  - url: https://example.net/api
security:
  - apiKey: []
paths:
  $ref: './employee/resource.api.yaml'
  $ref: './projects/resource.api.yaml'
  $ref: './customers/resource.api.yaml'
```

**Updated with file content:**
employee/resource.api.yaml

```
/employee/{id}
  get:
  ...
/employee/{id}/addresses
  get:
  ...
```

projects/resource.api.yaml

```
/projects/{id}
  get:
  ...
  put:
  ...
/projects/{id}/files
  get:
  ...
/projects/{id}/fies/{fileName}/Content
  get:
  ...
```

Comment: Related: [Split OpenAPI Paths into multiple path definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61340890/113116)

Comment: Btw, your *resource.api.yaml* file examples are missing the colon `:` at the end of the `/employee/{id}`, `/employee/{id}/addresses`, etc. lines. I assume it's just a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

The `paths` node itself does not support `$ref`. You can only reference the content of individual paths:

```yaml
paths:
  /employee/{id}:
    $ref: './employee/employeeById.yaml'

  /projects/{id}:
    $ref: './project/projectById.yaml'
```

employee/employeeById.yaml:

```yaml
get:
  operationId: ...
  summary: ...
  ...
```

project/projectById.yaml:

```yaml
get:
  operationId: ...
  summary: ...
  ...

put:
  operationId: ...
  summary: ...
  ...
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep your current *resource.api.yaml* files as is, the $refs would look as follows. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) for an explanation of how the `#/...` pointers are encoded in the `$ref` values.

```yaml
paths:
  /employee/{id}:
    $ref: './employee/resource.api.yaml#/employee~1%7Bid%7D'

  /employee/{id}/addresses:
    $ref: './employee/resource.api.yaml#/employee~1%7Bid%7D~1addresses'

  /projects/{id}:
    $ref: './project/resource.api.yaml#/projects~1%7Bid%7D'
```